# Boto3 and Flask: images are not uploading to S3 properly

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3

I am building a gallery for my Flask website and am having trouble generating thumbnails in my CMS. I have a function that takes the uploaded images (stored in a list), I duplicate the list, and use `zip()` to iterate through both of the lists. I make thumbnails with one list and I upload the full images with the other list and I send both to AWS S3. The issue is that I do make the thumbnails but the full images get uploaded as images with sizes of 0 bytes. I also have a function that renames the images. That is working, so I assume that I am doing something right.

Why am I getting files of 0 bytes? How does that happen? What is 'emptying' the file?

```py
@application.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("photo")
    conn = boto3.client(
        's3',
        region_name="region",
        aws_access_key_id='aws_access_key_id',
        aws_secret_access_key='aws_secret_access_key'
        )
    bucket_name = "bucket"
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        i = 1
        thumbs_list = list(uploaded_files)
        for z, w in zip(thumbs_list, uploaded_files):
            x = photo_rename(w)
            thumb = save_thumbnail(z)
            conn.upload_fileobj(x.stream, bucket_name, 'gallery/fulls/'+w.filename)
            conn.upload_fileobj(thumb, bucket_name, 'gallery/thumbs/'+w.filename)
            form_commit = Gallery(event=form.event.data,
                                  date=form.date.data,
                                  image_order=i,
                                  image_file_fl=w.filename,
                                  image_file_th=w.filename
                                  )
            db.session.add(form_commit)
            i += 1
        db.session.commit()
    return '', 204
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get both uploads to work using `io.BytesIO()` in my `for loop`:

```py
for z, w in zip(thumbs_list, uploaded_files):
            x = photo_rename(w)
            c = Image.open(x)
            in_mem_file = io.BytesIO()
            c.save(in_mem_file, "JPEG")
            in_mem_file.seek(0)
            thumb = save_thumbnail(z)
            conn.upload_fileobj(in_mem_file, bucket_name, 'gallery/fulls/'+w.filename)
```